# Accessing VMs (RDP) after getting owner(co-administrator) access to an Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

If I get owner(co-administrator) access for an Azure subscription, will I be able to RDP to any of the VMs(Windows) without be able to access login and passwords? As of now I don't have this special access, so not sure if after getting this access (co-administrator) if I will be able to see the usernames and passwords for all the VMs in the subscription no matter who created them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I get owner(co-administrator) access for an Azure subscription,
>   will I be able to RDP to any of the VMs(Windows) without be able to
>   access login and passwords?

Answer is "not exactly" because you still need to know the RDP credentials in order to remote into any virtual machine (there is no other magic connectivity route for co-admins other than standard RDP credentials AFAIK).

However, imagine a scenario where someone else created a VM and hasn't really shared the RDP credentials with you. If you are a co-administrator for the Azure subscription to which this VM belongs, you now have the power to reset RDP credentials to new ones, that you know about and then use these new credentials to RDP.

Here are the step-by-step instructions that can be followed to do this reset password for a Windows VM. [How to reset the Remote Desktop service or its login password in a Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-rdp)

**NOTE**: I mentioned "reset" and not add, so previously set credentials will no longer work.

[image]